# Derivative of $e^\sqrt{4x+4}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, exponentiation

$$f(x)=e^\sqrt{4x+4}$$

$f(x)=e^u$
$u=\sqrt{4x+4}=(4x+4)^{1/2}$
$u\;'=\dfrac{1}{2}(4x+4)^{-1/2}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{4x+4}}$

I don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the base and chain along the derivative of the exponent:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\sqrt{4x+4}}\right)=e^{\sqrt{4x+4}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(4x+4\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\left(4\right)=\boxed{\frac{2e^{\sqrt{4x+4}}}{\sqrt{4x+4}}.}
\end{equation}

Comment: So are we using the chain rule three times? $\dfrac{df}{dv} \times \dfrac{dv}{du} \times \dfrac{du}{dx}$?

Comment: You're using it twice in this case. You write the base, chain along the immediate derivative of the exponent, and then since there was something to chain along further we did it again with the $4x+4$ inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $\dfrac {\operatorname d \!e^{f(x)}}{\operatorname d \!x}=e^{f(x)} \dfrac {\operatorname d \!f}{\operatorname d \!x}$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=e^\sqrt{4x+4}\times \frac12 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x+4}} \times 4=e^\sqrt{4x+4}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}.$$

> **Notice that $$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))\times g'(x)$$**

Comment: Missed a $4$ there in the last term...